# Android AppLinks work without assetlinks.json

Tags: android, deep-linking

While working on a feature for my app with AppLinks for Android. I have realized that it actually works without using the assetlinks.json file.

At first, I thought that this was because my app was an app for debug purpose, which wasn't signed and published through the store and that for testing purposed, Google decided to give us some space to work.

The day I released my app arrived, I put my app through Beta, installed my app from the store and tapped on a https://example.com and I was very surprised to see that I got asked which app I wanted to open this URL even though I had not make the assetlinks.json available from https://example.com/.well-known/assetlink.json.

Is there an explanation to that ? 
Maybe the check is totally asynchronous and if at some point Google makes the check and find out you don't have this file, they shut it down until you fix it and ou have to wait until the next time they check you out ?

By the way, i have implemented the same functionality with iOS and in a very Apple-ish way, you really can't get around putting you apple-app-site-association file to the right spot and make it available from the right endpoint.

Thanks for the explanation :)

Guillaume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an explanation to that ?

What you describe has been the behavior since API Level 1 in 2008.

> I was very surprised to see that I got asked which app I wanted to open this URL

This is called a "chooser". The point behind `assetlinks.json` is *to avoid the chooser* and drive straight to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have an idea on how the checking works ? is it kind of instantaneous or is it like a crawl that Google would do every few days to check like they would do for the search engine ?

Comment: @bottus: It is closer to instantaneous. As part of the install process, Android tries checking the URLs.

Comment: Alright, thanks very much for the quick answer, I really appreciate.

Comment: We can basically say that as long as I get the chooser when trying to open a link, it means that there is a failure behind my asset links.json or that my user is prior to Android M, correct ?

Comment: @bottus: That sounds like a safe assessment. In principle, there could be a delay in validating the asset links (e.g., you're side-loading the app and there is no connectivity at the moment), but that should be an edge case at best.